# Mediawiki 1.26.2 - Stylesheet not working/loading

Tags: php, css, mediawiki

I have downloaded and installed Mediawiki latest version 1.26.2. In this version, the stylesheet is not working/loading. In older version (1.23.5) of Mediawiki installed on same server, its working fine. I have checked LocalSettings.php file multiple times and everything seems to be fine.

Anyone facing same issue?

Edit - Adding further details to make my problem clearer

The Mediawiki 1.26.2 site is deployed as a directory in a website under IIS (Windows 2012 server). In same website, Mediawiki 1.23.5 is deployed under different directory. Mediawiki 1.23.5 stylesheet works. However for 1.26.2 it did not.

Here is a snapshot of deployment configuration.

[image]

I also tried deploying Mediawiki 1.26.2 under a new website "MediawikiNew' just to be sure that directory inside a website is not creating any problem. But still that didn't worked.

[image]

I tried both with http and https protocol but it did not made any difference.

I am mentioning here my LocalSettings.php file of Mediawiki 1.26.2 (When deployed under directory inside website)

```
<?php
# This file was automatically generated by the MediaWiki 1.26.2
# installer. If you make manual changes, please keep track in case you
# need to recreate them later.
#
# See includes/DefaultSettings.php for all configurable settings
# and their default values, but don't forget to make changes in _this_
# file, not there.
#
# Further documentation for configuration settings may be found at:
# https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuration_settings

# Protect against web entry
if ( !defined( 'MEDIAWIKI' ) ) {
    exit;
}

## Uncomment this to disable output compression
# $wgDisableOutputCompression = true;

$wgSitename = "Mediawiki1.26.2";

## The URL base path to the directory containing the wiki;
## defaults for all runtime URL paths are based off of this.
## For more information on customizing the URLs
## (like /w/index.php/Page_title to /wiki/Page_title) please see:
## https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL
$wgScriptPath = "/mediawiki-1.26.2";
$wgScriptExtension = ".php";

## The protocol and server name to use in fully-qualified URLs
$wgServer = "http://localhost/";

## The URL path to static resources (images, scripts, etc.)
$wgResourceBasePath = $wgScriptPath;

## The URL path to the logo.  Make sure you change this from the default,
## or else you'll overwrite your logo when you upgrade!
$wgLogo = "$wgResourceBasePath/resources/assets/wiki.png";

## UPO means: this is also a user preference option

$wgEnableEmail = true;
$wgEnableUserEmail = true; # UPO

$wgEmergencyContact = "apache@bp1amsapt221.cloudapp.net";
$wgPasswordSender = "apache@bp1amsapt221.cloudapp.net";

$wgEnotifUserTalk = false; # UPO
$wgEnotifWatchlist = false; # UPO
$wgEmailAuthentication = true;

## Database settings
$wgDBtype = "mysql";
$wgDBserver = "<secret>";
$wgDBname = "<secret>";
$wgDBuser = "<secret>";
$wgDBpassword = "<secret>";

# MySQL specific settings
$wgDBprefix = "";

# MySQL table options to use during installation or update
$wgDBTableOptions = "ENGINE=InnoDB, DEFAULT CHARSET=binary";

# Experimental charset support for MySQL 5.0.
$wgDBmysql5 = false;

## Shared memory settings
$wgMainCacheType = CACHE_NONE;
$wgMemCachedServers = array();

## To enable image uploads, make sure the 'images' directory
## is writable, then set this to true:
$wgEnableUploads = true;
#$wgUseImageMagick = true;
#$wgImageMagickConvertCommand = "/usr/bin/convert";

# InstantCommons allows wiki to use images from https://commons.wikimedia.org
$wgUseInstantCommons = false;

## If you use ImageMagick (or any other shell command) on a
## Linux server, this will need to be set to the name of an
## available UTF-8 locale
$wgShellLocale = "en_US.utf8";

## If you want to use image uploads under safe mode,
## create the directories images/archive, images/thumb and
## images/temp, and make them all writable. Then uncomment
## this, if it's not already uncommented:
#$wgHashedUploadDirectory = false;

## Set $wgCacheDirectory to a writable directory on the web server
## to make your wiki go slightly faster. The directory should not
## be publically accessible from the web.
#$wgCacheDirectory = "$IP/cache";

# Site language code, should be one of the list in ./languages/Names.php
$wgLanguageCode = "en";

$wgSecretKey = "3e7c50e485e082453ec47a29c70ffd76925bbe00d0185058a870ef474bb71f55";

# Site upgrade key. Must be set to a string (default provided) to turn on the
# web installer while LocalSettings.php is in place
$wgUpgradeKey = "dbdeb53536b08e21";

## For attaching licensing metadata to pages, and displaying an
## appropriate copyright notice / icon. GNU Free Documentation
## License and Creative Commons licenses are supported so far.
$wgRightsPage = ""; # Set to the title of a wiki page that describes your license/copyright
$wgRightsUrl = "";
$wgRightsText = "";
$wgRightsIcon = "";

# Path to the GNU diff3 utility. Used for conflict resolution.
$wgDiff3 = "";

## Default skin: you can change the default skin. Use the internal symbolic
## names, ie 'vector', 'monobook':
$wgDefaultSkin = "vector";

# Enabled skins.
# The following skins were automatically enabled:
wfLoadSkin( 'CologneBlue' );
wfLoadSkin( 'Modern' );
wfLoadSkin( 'MonoBook' );
wfLoadSkin( 'Vector' );


# Enabled Extensions. Most extensions are enabled by including the base extension file here
# but check specific extension documentation for more details
# The following extensions were automatically enabled:
wfLoadExtension( 'Cite' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Gadgets' );
wfLoadExtension( 'ImageMap' );
wfLoadExtension( 'InputBox' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Nuke' );
wfLoadExtension( 'ParserFunctions' );
wfLoadExtension( 'PdfHandler' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Renameuser' );
wfLoadExtension( 'SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi' );
wfLoadExtension( 'WikiEditor' );


# End of automatically generated settings.
# Add more configuration options below.
```

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @Paulie - Apologies. I have added more details to make my question clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. The problem was that PHP.exe did not had write access to temp folder where it creates temp files during application execution. This was fine with older versions of MediaWiki (E.g. - MediaWiki-1.23.5). However latest version (E.g. - Mediawiki-1.26.2) do not loads styles due to this problem.

I was able to resolve this problem by taking help of MediaWiki support.

Posting the resolution here so that it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

This version was trying to write files into temp folder and it does not have permission, so it was not working.

Solution:
Give Full permission to C:\Windows\Temp